# Optimal Mix / constrained optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm looking to solve a constrained optimization problem. I'm running into trouble with the number of inputs:

- Say $Z$ is the output I want to maximize, subject to a budget constraint of $\Sigma x \leq \$ 1,000,000$.
- $Z$ is the sum of each $Q_i$, $ \ Z= Q_1+Q_2+Q_3+Q_4+Q_5$.

  1. $Q_1 = 5+ 0.5\ln(x_1)$
  2. $Q_2 = 3+ 0.7\ln(x_2)$
  3. $Q_3 = 2+ 0.3\ln(x_3)$
  4. $Q_4 = 4+ 0.9\ln(x_4)$
  5. $Q_5 = 6+ 1.6\ln(x_5)$

I want to choose the optimal combination of $x_i$ for each of the inputs to maximize $Z$, subject to the overall budget constraint.

I suspect this is a fairly basic optimization problem; can somebody point me in the right direction to where such a problem has been discussed?

Comment: You can do this using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Jacob. MuadDib42, I assumed Langrangian multipliers would be the way to go; where I'm having trouble is in the basic setup. Would I view each Qi as a separate constraint, so then the Langrangian function is going to be l(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5)? If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can just substitute $Q_i$ values such as
$$\text{max}_{x_i} \big(5+0.5\ln(x_1)+3+0.7\ln(x_2)+2+0.3\ln(x_3)+4+0.9\ln(x_4)+6+1.6\ln(x_5)\big)$$
$$\text{subject to }x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\le 1.000.000$$
Since the objective function is increasing w.r.t. every $x_i$ we can reformulate the constraint to be
$$\text{subject to }x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5= 1.000.000$$
and the Lagrangian formulation becomes
$$L=\big(20+0.5\ln(x_1)+0.7\ln(x_2)+0.3\ln(x_3)+0.9\ln(x_4)+1.6\ln(x_5)\big)+\lambda\big(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5- 1.000.000\big)$$
and you can solve for first-order conditions.
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}=0$$

Comment: Occupy, that's really helpful and makes sense. Only question I have is: Say my objective function is a mixed bag-- it is not increasing with respect to each xi (i.e., there are instances such as -75+0.5ln(xi)). Would it still be accurate to formulate the constraint as x1+x2+x3+x4+x5=1,000,000? It makes intuitive sense to do so, based on the constraint...

Comment: You may need a slack variable depending on the context; but in general you can do it.